# Sitecore.Context.Item is NULL during Ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

Think of a scenario, where page has to render certain contents based on current sitecore item referenced by using

```
Sitecore.Context.Item
```

However, This breaks during the ajax call as Sitecore.Content.Item will be NULL.
Any work around for this would be very helpful

Thanks

Comment: @Div although it would be nice if OP was clearer in the question, I don't think your comment is helpful, which surely is the purpose of SO - to be helpful right? *Praveen* I have added a possible answer, but if you can add some detail that will help us identify your problem easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to make sure the `Sitecore.Context.Item` is populated for an ajax call that I know of, is to make the call to a Sitecore "page" rather than a web api end point.

The simplest way to do this is to add a new Sitecore device, call it `Ajax` and set the `Query String` property to `ajax=true` or similar.

Then you can set the presentation on your item to an empty layout and controller action that runs the code you want and returns the out for the ajax call. This way the item resolve will set the context item properly and you can use that.